Does there exist a sequence such that all real numbers in [0,1] are subsequential limits?
Does there exist a sequence $a_n$, such that, for all  $a \in [0,1]$, there is some subsequence $\{a_{n_k}\}$ whose subsequential limit is $\lim\limits_{k\to+\infty}a_{n_k}=a$.
I suppose $a_n=|\sin n|$ is satisfied the property ,but i cann't prove it.
if you take a better example ,i will appreciate you .

You could take a sequence which enumerates $[0, 1] ∩ ℚ$.

Sorry , I don't understand your meaning.How to take a sequence which enumerates $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$?

a sequence that enumerates the rational numbers between 0 and 1 is not sufficient to ensure every real between 0 and 1 is a subsequential limit if each rational appears only once.

I think that it can make a circle that number on it such that each rational appers infinity times . I 'm not sure it is right . And how to write it strictly?

I know what you mean. Of you go along the circumference of a unit circle by moving one unit at a time, then, in principle, you can get as close you want to any given point on the circumference after sufficiently many steps, right?

Yes,but I found it is may not a good idea in this question

FYI, the possible sets of subsequence limits of a sequence of real numbers is equal to the set of nonempty closed subsets of the extended real numbers. That is, $[0,1]$ can be replaced with any nonempty closed subset of the extended real numbers, and no other set can be a set of subsequence limits of a sequence of real numbers. See Given closed $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ find a sequence with subsequences convergent to every point in $C$ and nowhere else and its linked questions.

@ColinTan Any enumeration of the rational numbers between $0$ and $1$ is sufficient. Why do you think that's not the case?

@ColinTan: Your first comment is almost correct: you just have to delete the word "not".

@123321lll, could I request perhaps you ask specifically whether the sequence ${|\sin(n) } $ has every real between 0 and 1 as a subsequential limit as a separate question?

@ColinTan ,sorry I see the comment now ,I will ask the question.

@ColinTan the question is there

thank you, 123321lll for asking.

@TonyK, actually, I still don't understand. Why does every enumeration of the rationals between 0 and 1 have every real as a subsequential limit? Could someone share a proof with me?

Do you know that each number in $[0,1]$ has a decimal expansion?  If so, perhaps you could use that.

@GEdgar, lets say we are thinking of $\pi - 3 = 0.14159\ldots$. But the numbers $0.1, 0.14, 0.141,\dots$ might not appear in ${a_n} $ in increasing order.

@ColinTan: Given $x\in[0,1]$ and an enumeration $(q_i)$, then for every $n$ there esists a rational $q_{i_n}$ within distance $1/n$ of $x$. The sequence $(q_{i_n})$ tends to $x$. (To make this work, we have to make $(i_n)$ a strictly increasing sequence, but this is easy to do.)

ok. Thanks, TonyK. User65023 has written up this solution as an answer.

@ColinTan... If the term 0.14 is not later in my enumeration, I could use 0.140 or 0.1400 etc.  One of these is later in my enumeration.

$0.14=0.140$. If by enumeration, you mean one $a_i$ for each rational number, then you cannot have both $0. 14$ and $0.140$ in your sequence.

Here's a very simple sequence:
$$\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5},\frac{3}{5},\frac{4}{5},\frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{6},\frac{3}{6},\frac{4}{6},\frac{5}{6},\frac{1}{7},\cdots$$

Arguably simpler: $$\frac12,\frac14,\frac24,\frac34,\frac18,\frac28,\cdots,\frac78,\frac1{16},\cdots$$

could you give a brief explanation why every real between 0 and 1 is a subsequential limit?

@ColinTan Let $a\in [0,1]$ and $\varepsilon >0$. Then when $\frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon$, a point of the form $\frac{k}{n}$ must be in the interval $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$.

Or $0,.1,.2,\dots,.9,.00,.01,.02,\dotsc,.99,.000,.001,.002,\dotsc,.999,\dotsc$.

thanks jjagmath.

Actually, take $a_n$ to be any dense sequence in $[0,1]$.  Any enumeration of the sequence works, because after any finite number of elements, the remaining tail of the sequence is still dense.  If the tail of any dense sequence wasn't dense, then the entire sequence wouldn't be dense.  Once you have a dense sequence, then for any real number $a \in [0,1]$, there exists a subsequence $n_k$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k} = a$.

This solution is based on Jean Abou Samra's comment.
Choose a bijection $f : \mathbb{N} \to ([0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}) \times \mathbb{N}$. Then the composite $a: \mathbb{N} \xrightarrow{f} ([0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}) \times \mathbb{N} \xrightarrow{\text{proj}_1}([0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}) $
defines a sequence $a(n)$, which is just the first coordinate of $f(n)$.
Then, for each given $c \in [0,1]$, choose a sequence $\{q_i\} $ of rationals between 0 and 1 that converges to $c$. Let $n_1$ be the least index such that $f(n_1) = (q_1, k_1)$ for some $k_1$. Then $a(n_1) = q_1$, by definition. For each $i > 1$, let $n_i > n_{i - 1}$ be the least index such that $f(n_i) = (q_i, k_i)$ for some $k_i$. Such $n_i$ exists since $q_i$ occurs as the first coordinate of $a(n) $ for infinitely many indices $n$. Then $a(n_i) = q_i$, by definition again.
Therefore $\lim a(n_i) =\lim q_i = c$.

Thank you for your answer . I notice a mistake $f$ is not bijection ,right ?

there exists a bijection $f$, since both its domain and codomain are countably infinite.

I remember $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is uncountably infinite by contor .

@123321lll  $[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ is a subset of $\Bbb Q$ so it's definitely countable.

yes ,I make a mistake.
